# TypeError: Cannot read property 'postID' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm pretty new to programming and I want to make a news/forum site for practice with one of the routes being /post/postID/postTitle to view the individual post. When I tried it with only :postID it worked, but now that I added :postTitle whenever I go to the URL it says:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'postID' of undefined."

My app.js:

```
var express = require("express")
    app = express()
    bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// ROUTES

// Root
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index");
});

// Login
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
  res.render("login");
});

// Register
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
  res.render("register");
});

// Home
app.get("/home", function(req, res){
  res.render("home");
});

// Posts
app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
  res.render("posts");
});

// Post
app.get("/post/:postID/:postTitle", function(req, res){
var postID = req.params.postID;
var postTitle = req.params.postTitle;

res.render("post", {postID: postID},{postTitle: postTitle});
});



// SERVER
app.listen(4000, function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log("OH NOES, SERVER CAN'T START!");
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Server has started.");
  }
});
```

The Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postID' of undefined
    at C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\app.js:38:26
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\Users\jayth\Desktop\Centurion\Projects\August 2017\Wabbit.gg - #PWGG08102017\Coding\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is what it was before I tried testing it.

// Post
app.get("/post/:postID/:postTitle", function(error, req, res){
  var postID = req.params.postID;
  var postTitle = req.params.postTitle;

  if(error){
    console.log("Page could not be found.");
  } else {
    console.log("Page has been found.");
  }

  res.render("post", {postID: postID},{postTitle: postTitle});
});

Comment: I just edited the post instead.

Comment: What are you typing in for a route? Or is the code failing even before you can try the route?

Answer (score -1):

You can use res.send() instead of res.render().And use this for getting the postID and postTitle together.Here is the code `res.send("postID:"+postID+"  "+"postTitle:"+postTitle);`

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. OP is invoking the `render` function because he is rendering a template with the details of a post.